# meanjs best practice to setup process evn for database

Tags: heroku, meanjs, mlab

In my attempt to get a 'hello world' skill with meanjs.org product, I cloned 0.4.2 and setup a mongolab account.

I opened > config > env > development.js, to setup db URL, where I have this:

```
  db: {
uri: process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://' + (process.env.DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost') + '/mean-dev',
```

For trial, I simply replaced process.env.MONGOLAB_URI with my URL from mongolab and everthing worked for sure, but I doubt this is the way to go. I see a Procfile there, may be I should specify the process.env.MONGOLAB_URI there? Where I could specify it, so that if I upload it to Heroku, say, it will setup the process.env.MONGOLAB_URI and no edit will be needed here please?

p.s. I googled and searched SOF

Answer (score 0):

Well just a small progress,
I got to my gulpfile.js and setup a task as:

```
gulp.task('setmydb', function () {
process.env.MONGOLAB_URI = 
'mongodb://mylogin:mypassword@ds157479.mlab.com:57479/meantst1';
});
```

Then at the end of the file, added into the task sequence:

```
// Run the project in development mode
gulp.task('default', function (done) {
runSequence('env:dev', 'lint', ['setmydb','nodemon', 'watch'], done);
});
```

Well it worked, but I'm still not sure if this indeed is how it must be done! So please help me get sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone else also needed, this is how I solved my problem:
[Setting configuration variables | Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

I first followed the Heroku [getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) and edited their app there, added this root:

```
app.get('/envtst', function(request, response) {
var xterm = process.env.XVAR ==='yes' ? 'yes' : 'no';
response.send(xterm);
});
```

Then pushed the app to Heroku and also setup my test variable XVAR via command line:

```
heroku config:set XVAR=yes
```

finally, opened the root in browser and verified.